# Wrapping multiple classes together of C++ for Python with Swig

Tags: python, swig

I am trying to wrap 7 classes of c++ together with `swig` and put them in same library. Following is my interface file to hold all the classes.

```
// File : quadedge.i to hold all the interface files together
%module quadedge
%include cell.i
%include list.i
%include face.i
%include edge.i
%include obj.i
%include array.i
%include vertex.i
```

with each interface file `cell.i`, `list.i`, ... being interface file

```
//file : list.i : interface file for list.hh
%module list

%{
#include "list.hh"
%}

%include list.hh
```

I used a disutil file `setup.py`to wrap the classes.

```
#setup.py file:
from setuptools import setup, Extension
setup(name='quadedge',
    version='0.1',
    ext_modules=[Extension('_quadedge', sources=['array.cc','edge.cc','list.cc','cell.cc','face.cc','obj.cc','vertex.cc', 'quadedge.i'],
                    swig_opts=['-c++'],
                    )],
    headers=['array.hh','edge.hh','list.hh','cell.hh','face.hh','obj.hh','vertex.hh',]
)
```

and running

```
 python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

it ran well with few warnings but the library was created. I then tried to import the `quadedge`library.

```
>>>import quadedge as qd
>>>a = qd.vertex()  
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-e068e492f5b5> in <module>()
----> 1 a = qd.vertex()

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'vertex'
```

I guess i did not understand well how SWIG wrapped the classes. I thought `quadedge`will be the main library with all other classes as sub-classes of this library.

Output of `dir(qd)`

```
['Cell',
 'CellFaceIterator',
 'CellFaceIterator_swigregister',
 'CellVertexIterator',
 'CellVertexIterator_swigregister',
 'Cell_kill',
 'Cell_make',
 'Cell_makeTetrahedron',
 'Cell_swigregister',
 'Edge',
 'Edge_kill',
 'Edge_make',
 'Edge_splice',
 'Edge_swigregister',
 'Face',
 'FaceEdgeIterator',
 'FaceEdgeIterator_swigregister',
 'Face_kill',
 'Face_make',
 'Face_swigregister',
 'Vertex',
 'VertexEdgeIterator',
 'VertexEdgeIterator_swigregister',
 'Vertex_kill',
 'Vertex_make',
 'Vertex_swigregister',
 '__builtins__',
 '__doc__',
 '__file__',
 '__name__',
 '__package__',
 '_newclass',
 '_object',
 '_quadedge',
 '_swig_getattr',
 '_swig_getattr_nondynamic',
 '_swig_property',
 '_swig_repr',
 '_swig_setattr',
 '_swig_setattr_nondynamic',
 'objCloneCell',
 'objReadCell',
 'objWriteCell']
```

Comment: What is the output of `dir(quadedge)` and `dir(qd)`?

Comment: hey @UlrichEckhardt I added the output of `dir(qd)`

Comment: ...and? Take a close look at it, to me it seems obvious.

Comment: Indeed, this is pretty obvious, but in case you're missing it: there is `Vertex` in the output, so you should write `a = guadedge.qd.Vertex()` instead.

Comment: hey @UlrichEckhardt and @AlexanderSolovets, I actually had minor mistake while writing the import statement in above description. I was supposed to write `import quadedge as qd` instead of `import quadedge.qd`, so i have corrected this. now still if i use `qd.vertex()` i get the same error and this is true for all other functions too. any suggestion on why is it happening even if there are all the functions inside the library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the case of the command. I was doing `qd.vertex()` where as the codes are case sensitive so it should be `qd.Vertex()`. A really stupid mistake took so much time to figure out.